# MySQL IF giving me BLOB

Tags: mysql

I have the following two lines in an SQL query:

```
if( tb2.show_count = 0, 'hidden', count( tb1.user_id ) ) as 'count'
if( tb2.show_name = 0, 'hidden', tb1.name ) as 'name'
```

The first line gives me `blob` and the second line returns either the `name` or `hidden` based on the value of `show_name`

How do I do the same for the first line?  i.e. stop it from giving me a `blob` and get it to return either the `count` or `hidden` based on the value of `show_count`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
if( tb2.show_count=0, 'hidden', cast(count(tb1.user_id) as char(10)) ) as 'count'
```

- if the results of an if evaluate to different types, they are returned as BLOBs, so the answer is to convert the count to a character type (the same as 'hidden').

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL Workbench, go to: "Edit -> Preferences... -> SQL Queries" OR "Edit -> Preferences... -> SQL Editor" (depending upon what version of Workbench you have).

Check the option 'Treat BINARY/VARBINARY as nonbinary character string' to show the actual value.

Comment: This did it for MySQL Workbench 8.0.20 except the "Treat BINARY/VARBINARY..." option was in  "Edit -> Preferences... -> SQL Execution"